# Fields aren't becoming lit after completing trial mode

Tags: gemcraft-0

I'm a lvl 69 wizard and recently started doing trial mode.
Quickly I had the achievement for 10 fields being lit in trial mode.
However (since I got the achievement?) completing trial mode no longer lights up the field.
Specifically the fields V3 and R4 will not light up after I win these fields.
I skipped the trial on V1, I cannot complete that one, could that be the reason?
Could there be another reason why the fields aren't lighting up?